# Mutt Direct Email Organization

Tags: email, mutt

I have been using the Mutt Terminal email client and have been enjoying it thus far. I am getting into some Linux Kernel programming lately and have recently become a part of the *lkml*(linux kernel mailing list). The lkml has tons of new messages flooding it each day. I want to make sure I don't miss a message that is sent directly to me.

How can I instruct Mutt so that I can I have my inbox filled with lkml messages and have another folder dedicated to displaying messages sent directly to me(Contains my email in the *To:* field)?

Comment: Are you using mutt for locally delivered mail, or are you using mutt to browse a remote mailbox? For the former, look at `procmail`. For the latter, look if the remote mailbox has different folders and automation for it.

Comment: Close voter: how is this even remotely off-topic?

Comment: @dirkt I am using mutt with a remote, my gmail.

Comment: You need to create a filter in gmail (using  the web interface) to separate mail messages; that is a task for the mail transport agent (MTA), not the mail user agent (MUA, in your case mutt). BTW it's more usual to keep personal emails in the main mailbox and store mailinglist messages and such into separate mailboxes.

Comment: Please specify if you use mutt on a local inbox (Maildir/mbox?) or on a  mailbox on a remote server via IMAP.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for another mailbox. You can use limit to filter matching messages with pattern modifier ~C - matches messages either To: or CC:.

Just hit `l` on the index and type: `~C youremail@example.com`